# Ejecución macro para envío de correos

Tags: excel, vba, email, macros

Tengo un Excel que contiene varias hojas y cada una de ellas tiene un botón de control que al darle click, ejecuta una macro que lo que hace es adjuntar en un cuerpo de correo de Outlook un rango de celdas ( en este caso,una tabla de precios), a una dirección de correo determinada y con un Asunto determinado. Cada una de estar macros se ejecuta bien. Lo que quiero hacer es una macro general con optro botón de control que al activarlo me ejecute todas las macros de golpe.

tengo el siguiente macro que me funciona, pero no se adjunta el rango de celdas en el cuerpo del mensaje y no sé dónde está el error:

```vb
Sub EjecutarTodasLasMacros()
    Call Macro1
    Call Macro2
    'Agrega aquí todas las macros que deseas ejecutar
End Sub
```

En `Macro1` y `Macro2` substituyo por el nombre de mis otras macros.

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hay que ver qué hace cada una de esas macros de forma individual. Es probable que en alguna se necesite tener la hoja activa para copiar los datos y al estar en otra hoja no te funcione. Pero sin verlo es complicado.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque supongo que lo tendrás bien, si sabes enviar con macro un correo, lo unico que se me ocurre sin ver las macros es:

```vb
Sub EjecutarTodasLasMacros()
   Call Macro1 
   Call Macro2 
   'Agrega aquí todas las macros que deseas ejecutar 
End Sub
```

o

```vb
Sub EjecutarTodasLasMacros():    Call Macro1 : Call Macro2 :   End Sub
```

Si pudieras mostrar código para enviar correo mediante macro, lo agradecería